# PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in

Tags: php, pdo

I am getting this error when trying to access my site.

Say the error is on line 11

The path of DB_ACCOUNT is being made through htaccess

Can someone help me?

Edit .: I put the connection part but it didn't work either.

```
<?php

if (isset($_SESSION['id'])):
    $painel = 'inline';
    $pglogin = 'none';
else:
    $painel = 'none';
    $pglogin = 'inline';
endif;

define('DB_HOST', '11.1.1.1.');
define('DB_USER', 'test');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'xxxxxxx');

define('DB_ACCOUNT', 'account');


try {
    $conexao = new PDO('mysql:host='.DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'));
    $conexao->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);    
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

$query = $conexao->prepare('SELECT * FROM '.DB_ACCOUNT.'.account WHERE login = :login');
$query->bindValue(':login', $_SESSION['login']);
$query->execute();
$row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);
$confemail = 'none';
if ($query->rowCount() > 0):
    if ($row['status'] == 'WEBBLK'):
        $pglock = 'none';
        $pgunlock = 'inline';
    else:
        $pglock = 'inline';
        $pgunlock = 'none';
    endif;

    if ($row['status'] == 'BLOCK' && $row['active_conta'] > 0):
        $confemail = 'inline';
    else:
        $confemail = 'none';
    endif;
endif;

?>
```

Comment: `$conexao` doesn't exist in your code, what are you expecting?

Comment: @Jonnix 
It has been added but the error persists.

Comment: Check the error in the chatch, most likely that causes it to not be initialized

Comment: `define('DB_HOST', '11.1.1.1.');` extra dot at the end?

Comment: @Matt This ip was just an example. Disregard that extra point.

Comment: You left out critical components of your source before. Have you now posted the _complete_ thing? Censoring of hosts/creds of course is ok. And what do the logs say?

Comment: Please post the error message in full and show us which line of code is responsible